# Are Puppet virtual resources auto-realized if they're auto-required?

Tags: puppet

It's [documented](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.18/types/file.html) that Puppet will auto-require certain resources, e.g. a (puppet-managed) directory that is a parent of a `File` resource, or a `group` resource referenced in a `user` resource.

If an auto-required resource has been declared as a [virtual resource](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/6.18/lang_virtual.html), is it necessary to explicitly realize that resource, or will the auto-require cause it to happen implicitly?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the answer is that virtual resources are **not** automatically realized if they're auto-required.    The following manifest will result in a "No such file or directory" error:`

```
@file { '/foo':
  ensure => directory
}

file { '/foo/test':
  content => 'this is a test file'
}
```

but works fine if the virtual resource is explicitly realized with:

```
realize File['/foo']
```